# git cherry-pick earlier patch-set version

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a patch that I cherry-picked from Gerrit at patch-set 10, A colleague then updated the patch in gerrit to patch-set 11.

I didn't  see this so i pushed a rebased version of patch-set 10 back to gerrit - now missing the fixes in patch-set 11

My thought was, that I could just rebase out the patch locally and then cherry-pick patch-set 11 again. This does however not seem to happen.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git fetch ssh:/user@xx.xx.xx.xx:29418/Project/abc/def refs/changes/17/351617/11 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Instead I get latest version of the patch again (I can see this as the code wont build with the version of the patch I get)

I also tried cherry-picking the hash of patch-set 11 directly but result was still that I get the code from patch-set 10 (or 12).

So is there a way of forcing git to actually use patch-set 11 and not some other version it gets from its history ?